# What font is used on the ThinkPad X41 keyboard?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

See the below image of a keyboard of an [IBM ThinkPad X41](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X41). *What is the font 
used for labeling the keys?*

Note that the font is used on many, if not all, ThinkPad keyboards. However, I
am not sure about that, and that's the reason why I stayed specific to the X41
keyboard.

Image at full resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4kd4.png

[image: Scan of keyboard top]

Answer (score 1):

Looks very much like Helvetica

Comment: Yes. **G, R** and **1** are the characteristic glyphs to differentiate Helvetica from similar fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Check pending. Also note the non-ASCII characters: `Ö`, `Ä`, etc.